# Custom button in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, design-view

I was wondering if it's possible to make more of the styling buttons in the design view.  Right now it's fairly limited, not having buttons for line breaks or divs.  Is there a plugin for that or do I have to do it myself, and would this be hard to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for this.

http://ditio.net/2010/08/15/adding-custom-buttons-to-wordpress-tinymce/

Comment: Thanks, I read it then googled "enhanced TinyMCE" - I found this: http://www.my-blog-review.com/wordpress-visual-editor-plugin-tinymce-advanced/